# Computed property from @Published array of objects not updating SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui, computed-properties

I have a StateController class:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class StateController: ObservableObject {
    
    // Array of subjects loaded in init() with StorageController
    @Published var subjects: [Subject]
    
    private let storageController = StorageController()
    
    init() {
        self.subjects = storageController.fetchData()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Computed properties
    
    // Array with all tasks from subjects, computed property
    var allTasks: [Task] {
        var all: [Task] = []
        
        for subject in subjects {
            all += subject.tasks
        }
        print("Computed property updated!")
        return all
    }

    var numberofCompletedTasks: Int {
        return subjects.map({$0.tasks.map({$0.isCompleted == true})}).count
    }
    
    var numberOfHighPriorityTasks: Int {
        return subjects.map({$0.tasks.map({$0.priority == 1})}).count
    }
    var numberOfMediumPriorityTasks: Int {
        return subjects.map({$0.tasks.map({$0.priority == 2})}).count
    }
    var numberOfLowPriorityTasks: Int {
        return subjects.map({$0.tasks.map({$0.priority == 3})}).count
    }
}
```

And a SwiftUI view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SmartList: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    let title: String
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var stateController: StateController
    
    // MARK: - View body
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(stateController.allTasks, id: \.taskID) { task in
            
            TaskView(task: task)
                .environmentObject(self.stateController)
            
        }.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .navigationTitle(LocalizedStringKey(title))
    }
}
```

When I update "Task" objects inside "subjects" @Published array, for example checking them as complete, SwiftUI should automatically update the view because computed properties are derived from @Published property of an ObservableObject (declared as @EnvironmentObject inside view) but it doesn't work.

How can I bind my SwiftUI view to computed properties derived from a @Published property??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, SwiftUI automatically updating views that are displaying computed properties when an `@EnvironmentObject`/`@ObservedObject` changes only works in very limited circumstances. Namely, the `@Published` property itself cannot be a reference type, it needs to be a value type (or if it's a reference type, the whole reference needs to be replaced, simply updating a property of said reference type won't trigger an `objectWillChange` emission and hence a `View` reload).

Because of this, you cannot rely on computed properties with SwiftUI. Instead, you need to make all properties that your view needs stored properties and mark them as `@Published` too. Then you need to set up a subscription on the `@Published` property, whose value you need for your computed properties and hence update the value of your stored properties each time the value they depend on changes.

```
class StateController: ObservableObject {

    // Array of subjects loaded in init() with StorageController
    @Published var subjects: [Subject]

    @Published var allTasks: [Task] = []

    private let storageController = StorageController()

    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.subjects = storageController.fetchData()
        // Closure for calculating the value of `allTasks`
        let calculateAllTasks: (([Subject]) -> [Task]) = { subjects in subjects.flatMap { $0.tasks } }
        // Subscribe to `$subjects`, so that each time it is updated, pass the new value to `calculateAllTasks` and then assign its output to `allTasks`
        self.$subjects.map(calculateAllTasks).assign(to: \.allTasks, on: self).store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `sink(receiveValue:)` with `[weak self]` instead of `assign(to:)` in classes - see [Does ‘assign(to:)’ produce memory leaks?](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546)

Comment: @pawello2222 wasn't aware of that bug, thanks for pointing it out